# Align vertically center of the div

Tags: html, css

I have the following code:

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
}
section {
  height: 70%;
}
.first {
  height: 10%;
}
.second {
  height: 10%;
}
.third {
  height: 10%;
}
```

```html
<section class="main-container">
  <div class="first">
    content goes here
  </div>
  <div class="second">
    content goes here
  </div>
  <div class="third">
    content goes here
  </div>
</section>
```

I need the content of `first`, `second` and `third` classes should be vertically aligned center.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vertically align text in a div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939914/vertically-align-text-in-a-div)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Using Flex**

```css
body,html {
  height: 100%;
}
section {
  height: 70%;
  display:flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  
}
.first {
  height: 10%;
  background:green;
}
.second {
  height: 10%;
  background:blue;
}
.third {
  height: 10%;
  background:orange;
}
```

```html
<section class="main-container">
  <div class="first">
    content goes here
  </div>
  <div class="second">
    content goes here
  </div>
  <div class="third">
    content goes here
  </div>
</section
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to using css3 flexbox, you can do like this:

```css
.main-container {
    height:calc(100vh);
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: nowrap;
    -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-align-content: center;
    -ms-flex-line-pack: center;
    align-content: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.first,
.second,
.third {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}
```

```html
<section class="main-container">
  <div class="first">
    content goes here
  </div>
  <div class="second">
    content goes here
  </div>
  <div class="third">
    content goes here
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding the below CSS will bring the text to vertically middle of divs

```
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
```

For better result you can give below style to outer div.

```
display:table;
```

Comment: You should set a snippet or a fiddle to demonstrate this ( even works in IE8) :)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest is to use flex .

You should mind that `height: xx%;` requires a known height value on parent to be calculated. Here `body{height:100%}` is `100%` of nothing (so for the children) **since html has no height set**.

```css
html,
body,
section{
  height: 100%;/* section inherits height value from body which inherits it from html */
  margin: 0;
}

section,
.first,
.second,
.third {
  margin:0;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width:100%;
}
section {
}
.first {
  height: 10%;
}
.second {

  flex: 1;
  background:gray
}
.third {
  height: 10%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <section class="main-container">
    <div class="first">
      // content goes here
    </div>
    <div class="second">
      // content goes here
    </div>
    <div class="third">
      // content goes here
    </div>
  </section>
</body>
```

**or did you mean  center site content in the middle which flex does easily too** *(same CSS rules but no flex imbrication needed here )*:

```css
html,
body,
section{
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

section
{
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width:100%;
  background:gray
}
section {
}
.first {
  height: 10%;
}
.second {
  height: 10%;
  background:lightgray
}
.third {
  height: 10%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <section class="main-container">
    <div class="first">
      // content goes here
    </div>
    <div class="second">
      // content goes here
    </div>
    <div class="third">
      // content goes here
    </div>
  </section>
</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

## [Check This out](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-align.asp)

## INLINE CSS

```
<div class="section" style="text-align:center">...</div>
```

## PURE CSS

```
.section {
    text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: I understood he was looking for vertical centering, not horizontal :)

Comment: yyyep, realized that now